# Meteor - return inside of a Tracker.autorun function not returning anything

Tags: reactjs, meteor

The function `renderNotes()` is supposed to return the mapped array which is in a separate file.  I noticed that when I return some JSX nothing returns to the screen.  I think I know the reason why is because it is returning the info to the tracker function.  How would I get the info to return to the `renderNotes()` function while inside the tracker.autorun() function?

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Accounts } from "meteor/accounts-base";
import { Tracker } from "meteor/tracker";

import SubjectRoutes from "./subjectRoutes/subjectRoutes";
import { Notes } from "../methods/methods"
import Menu from "./Menu.js";

class Home extends React.Component{
  componentWillMount() {
    if(!Meteor.userId()){
      this.props.history.replace("/login")
    }
  }
  logoutUser(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    Accounts.logout(() => {
      this.props.history.push("/login");
    });
  }
  renderNotes(){
    Tracker.autorun(function () {
      Meteor.subscribe('notes');
      let notes = Notes.find().fetch();
      // return notes.map((note) => {
      //   return <p>{note.imageURL}</p>
      // })
      return <p>asdas</p> //<--Here
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.logoutUser.bind(this)}>Logout</button>
        {this.renderNotes()}
        <Menu />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Comment: Just at a glance, you need to think through what `renderNotes` is doing, and _when_ you are subscribing. As you have it, you are re-subscribing each time the function within `autorun` is called.

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner, what would be the result in putting the subscribe outside of the tracker.autorun function, faster experience since you don't have to keep subscribing? and how would I do the return problem I was asking about earlier?

Comment: Have you read [the guide on getting Meteor data into a React Component](https://guide.meteor.com/react.html#using-createContainer)? Think through data and component lifecycle. You subscribe once when the component mounts, (possibly) unsubscribe when it unmounts. The `renderNotes` function should be doing only one thing: rendering the correct elements. By the time that method is called (and rerun due to your subscription), your component should have the data it needs.

Comment: If you can just leave an answer on how I would solve my problem because as stated I am new to this, that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: More importantly than just throwing code your way, I'm trying to help you help yourself first.

Comment: I'm sorry but I have honestly no clue on a possible solution here, I've tried many things and things still seem to not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Accounts } from "meteor/accounts-base";
import { Tracker } from "meteor/tracker";

import SubjectRoutes from "./subjectRoutes/subjectRoutes";
import { Notes } from "../methods/methods"
import Menu from "./Menu.js";

class Home extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      notes: []
    }
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    if(!Meteor.userId()){
      this.props.history.replace("/login")
    }
    this.tracker = Tracker.autorun(()=>{
      Meteor.subscribe('notes');
      let notes = Notes.find().fetch();
      this.setState({ notes })
    });
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.tracker.stop();
  }
  logoutUser(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    Accounts.logout(() => {
      this.props.history.push("/login");
    });
  }
  renderNotes(notes){
    return notes.map((note) => {
      return (
        <div key={note._id}>
          <img src={note.imageURL} />
          <p>{note.type}</p>
        </div>
      )
    });
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.logoutUser.bind(this)}>Logout</button>
        <Menu />
        {this.renderNotes(this.state.notes)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default withRouter(Home);
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether this is a proper answer but I like to usually do something like this

```
    import TrackerReact from 'meteor/ultimatejs:tracker-react';
    import { Notes } from "../methods/methods";

    export default class Home extends TrackerReact(React.Component) {
        constructor(props,) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         subscription:{
          publishNotes: Meteor.subscribe("publish-Notes")
         }
        };
       }
       returnNotes(){
         return Notes.find().fetch();
       }

       render(){
       ...

       const stuff = this.returnNotes().map((note)=>{
        return <p>{note}</p>
       });

       return (
       ....
       {stuff}
       )
       }
    }
```

Comment: I actually already figured out a solution that is quite similar to this one, I will post it up and mark as answered so people know that I have found an answer